# c++ : operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I designed simple struct which is pretty similar to `std::pair`.

```
struct pii{
    int first;          
    int second;         
    pii (int _first=-1, int _second=-1)
            : first(_first), second(_second)    {}

    //
    pii& operator=(const pii &ref){
        first=ref.first;
        second=ref.second;
        return *this;
    }
    pii operator+(const pii &ref){
        return pii(first+ref.first, second+ref.second);
    }

    //
    bool operator<(pii &ref){
        if(first<ref.first && second<ref.second)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    bool operator>(pii &ref){
        return ref>(*this);
    }
    bool operator<=(pii &ref){
        return !((*this)>ref);
    }
    bool operator>=(pii &ref){
        return !((*this)<ref);
    }

    //
    bool operator==(pii &ref){
        if(first==ref.first && second==ref.second)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    bool operator!=(pii &ref){
        return !((*this)==ref);
    }
};
```

Let's assume there are two `pii` objects. I want to convert the following sentence using compare operations(`<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`, `==`, `!=`).

```
pii one, another;
//   I want to convert the below sentence.
if(one.first<=another.first && one.second<=another.second)
```

> `if(one<=another)`    //  it is not correct answer.

Is it possible to convert? then, What is the answer?

Comment: In `operator>` you have `ref>(*this);` You want to use `<` there.

Comment: No, you cannot represent that condition with the operators you have defined.

Comment: Warning: your `operator<` is not a Strict Weak Ordering.

Comment: @newbie -- Wouldn't it make more sense for `operator <` to compare `first` items, and if they're equal, compare `second`?  i.e. `std::tie(first, second) < std::tie(ref,first, ref.second);`  [std::tie](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie).

Answer (score 0):

This should be the correct code to compare the first and second variables:

```
bool operator<(pii &ref){
    return first<ref.first && second<ref.second;
}
bool operator>(pii &ref){
    return first>ref.first && second>ref.second;
}
bool operator<=(pii &ref){
    return first<=ref.first && second<=ref.second;
}
bool operator>=(pii &ref){
    return first>=ref.first && second>=ref.second;
}
```